# Setting SourceSwitch in VB.Net application code not config

Tags: vb.net

In VB.Net using the built in logging library and all the defaults, e.g.

```
My.Application.Log.WriteEntry("I am Warning", TraceEventType.Warning)
```

Is sufficient for my needs and I do not need to create any loggers, etc, it just works. However, in order to change the logging level I have to do this:

```
<switches>  
  <add name="SourceSwitch" value="Error"></add>  
</switches>
```

In my app.config.

I would prefer to do it in code but I cannot figure out how, or get my hands on the trace/logger created by the default application logger.

Any idea?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To set the logging level, it is pretty straight forward. You set the [SourceSwitch.Level Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.sourceswitch.level?view=netframework-4.8) of the [Log.TraceSource Property's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.logging.log.tracesource?view=netframework-4.8) [Switch Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracesource.switch?view=netframework-4.8).

```
My.Application.Log.TraceSource.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.Error
```